# how can I use grpc in c++ for generate service in proto files?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I have to use with grpc in c++, I have errors when I run the command for generate proto files.
where I can find grpc plugin for cpp?
thanks;)

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to get all the **libraries** and **plugins** for gRPC is to use [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg).

Just follow the description from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57472764/6199963).
After you have installed the gRPC-package with vcpkg, you can find everything you need in the "*vcpkg-folder*".

- Protoc: "*path_to_vcpkg*"/packages/protobuf_xX-XX/tools/protobuf
- Plugins: "*path_to_vcpkg*"/packages/grpc_x64-linux/tools/grpc
- CmakeToolchainFile: "*path_to_vcpkg*"/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake

### To produce your C++ proto-files use the following command:

```
path_to_vcpkg/packages/protobuf_xX-XX/tools/protobuf/protoc -I ./path_to_your_proto_files --cpp_out=./path_where_to_output --grpc_out=./path_where_to_output --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=./path_to_your_plugin/grpc_cpp_plugin path_to_your_proto_file/Target.proto
```

This approach also works if you want to **cross-compile** your application on different operating systems. Another advantage of vcpkg is that it gives you all the packages and libraries **precompiled**, so you don't have to spend hours compiling gRPC for C++. ;)