# why there is no precompiled c++ library for grpc

Tags: c++, grpc

I'm trying to integrate grpc into C++ projects. but I found the only way is download all source code and compile it by my self.

Is there any way to get a precompile .so/.a file which I can link against and a grpc_cpp_plugin for Linux?

Or is it impossible for c++ to do so and why?

Comment: It's not impossible for c++ but why can you not build it yourself? I've never used GRPC before but I looked through their docs and it's a simple call to `make` to compile the source.

Comment: @BradyDean because it need lots of third_party dependecies. I cannot only download source code of grpc. I'm trying to checkout from git and setup dependencies by git submodule. It need over 1GB disk space and a very long time to download them.

Comment: That will probably be the only way to do it. After building, run `make install` to a separate directory and use that as your own distribution of GRPC. Just delete the build files after.

Comment: See https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/18260 for discussion on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for precompiled gRPC libraries you should go with [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg).
I was also trying to cross compile gRPC, without building the library itself. With [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) I achieved this quite well.
There are just a few steps to set this up:

1. Pull vcpkg from GitHub and follow the instructions to set it up
2. Install grpc with "**./vcpkg install grpc**"
3. Set CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE in your **CMakeLists.txt** to the "*vcpkg.cmake*"-file in your vcpkg-folder
4. Add gRPC in your **CMakeLists.txt**

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

if(DEFINED ENV{VCPKG_ROOT})
    set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE $ENV{VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)
else()
    set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "/path_to_vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
endif()

project(Foo)

find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)

...

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Bar})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE gRPC::gpr gRPC::grpc gRPC::grpc++ gRPC::grpc_cronet)
```

In the Folder **path_to_vcpkg/packages/grpc_x64-PLATFORM/tools/grpc** you will find all the precompiled grpc-plugins for your platform (also **grpc_cpp_plugin**).

**Pros:**

- easy to set up
- vcpkg is available for all common plattforms
- if a package isn't needed anymore you can just delete the folder in "*path_to_vcpkg/packages*"
- includes all the gRPC tools you need

**Cons:**

- the "*path_to_vcpkg/packages*" folder gets quite big after some packages installed

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any way to get a precompile .so/.a file which I can link against and a grpc_cpp_plugin for Linux?

To answer this question, the gRPC C++ plugin currently requires manual build and install as stated here: https://grpc.io/blog/installation/

That means that there are currently no precompiled gRPC C++ plugins.

Comment: I looked at this too. But why the official doesn't provide precompiled version as they provide for all other languages?

Comment: @user2669704 That's left to speculation. Too many different types of systems and configurations maybe?